# Can no longer deploy a webapp using Yeoman, Grunt and Bower even after reinstalling

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, bower, yeoman

I have deployed many webapps using Yeoman, Grunt and Bower. Recently, though, when I ran `yo webapp`, and opted in for SASS, although it built successfully, it gave the following error in the top right corner of my screen (MAC OS 10.10.5):

[image]

(Expanded message):

[image]

I could still run the webapp with `grunt serve`, and it was functioning, although whenever I tried to change the relevant path in my main.scss, something would automatically change it back upon saving, and the above error message would return.

In an effort to resolve this, I tried reinstalling npm, node, bower and grunt. After no effect, I tried completely uninstalling node and npm as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31102612/4637110), and then reinstalling from fresh. My npm version is 2.14.3 and my node version is 4.1.0.

Now, I am completely unable to deploy a webapp using `yo webapp`. Here is the error, the warning seems to be related to Bower:

[image]

There are similar problems when running other webapps, such as the official angular webapp.

How can I resolve this situation?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `bower install` step didn't go through (in both cases):

- before you reinstall: it couldn't find bootstrap scss file (the `bower install` might have fail on this dependency)
- after you reinstall: it cannot find **any** bower packages.

Try to run `bower install`.

You'll find out some errors (like you're behind some proxy or your git clone is failing ...)

If you still have a file import problem: In `app/styles/main.scss`, remove the comments (`bower:scss` and `endbower`).

Comment: Thanks, I reinstalled bower and that did solve some issues. However, I'm still getting that SCSS error whenever I deploy. No error messages in console.

Comment: Check the import link in your `app/styles/main.scss` , does the file called on line 4 exists (read the warning) ?

Comment: Yes, so I change it to `@import "../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";` which works fine, until I save, at which point something is automatically reverting that line to `@import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";` and the error message persists

Comment: For your file import problem: In `app/styles/main.scss`, remove the comments (`bower:scss` and `endbower`).